# Add a custom header to Aurelia Fetch request

Tags: javascript, cors, aurelia, fetch-api

I'm trying to use Aurelia's Fetch Client to add a custom header to all GET and POST request.  The following code (in **app.js** constructor) works to set the base URL but the headers are not working the way I want:

```
constructor(httpClient) {
  // set up httpClient
  httpClient.configure(config => {
    config
      .withBaseUrl(localsettings.api)
      .withDefaults({
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'my_appkey': 'f2eabc5e7de-a4cdc857e'
        }
      })
  });
  this.httpClient = httpClient;
}
```

Usage:

```
this.httpClient.fetch(suburl, {
    credentials: 'include'
  }).then(response => { ... });
```

Through Chrome's development tools, I can see that the "my_appkey" header exists but it's not being created as it's own header and its value is not visible:

**Request Headers:**

```
OPTIONS /index.php/api/v1/keys HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: my_appkey
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es-419;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why is my custom header being moved into `Access-Control-Request-Headers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `my_appkey` header to the request triggers the browser to first perform [a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) before attempting the actual `GET`/`POST` request you want to make.

```
OPTIONS /index.php/api/v1/keys HTTP/1.1
^^^^^^^
```

As part of that preflight `OPTIONS`, the browser sends an [`Access-Control-Request-Headers` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Request-Headers) whose value includes the names of headers you’ve added to the request from your code.

> The Access-Control-Request-Headers request header is used when issuing a preflight request to let the server know which HTTP headers will be used when the actual request is made.

So what you’re seeing is all expected behavior.

And in order for the browser to consider that preflight `OPTIONS` request a success, the server the request is made to must send a response that has an [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers) whose value also includes "`my_appkey`". If it does not, then the browser stops right there and never proceeds to send the actual `GET`/`POST` request you want to make.

Comment: So, analyzing this, perhaps adding a custom header isn't the best way to go since it will slow down the request (the preflight request will add more latency, it would seem).  What would be a faster way to pass the appkey with all requests?  Just include it as part of the body?

Comment: Yeah if you want to avoid the extra request, I guess sending the appkey as part of the request body instead of a header would be the simplest way to do that. That said, if you really want fast, you could host your app code on same server/origin as the API endpoint

Comment: If they were hosted on the same subdomain (e.g. myapp.school.edu) then fetch would send the header without the need to do a preflight request?

Comment: Yes if they were hosted on the same origin (scheme + host + port) then it wouldn’t be a cross-origin request, so the browser wouldn’t impose any cross-origin restrictions, and wouldn’t use the CORS protocol at all—which means the request would succeed even without the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header being needed.